# Jumbotron background is not responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've been trying to find a solution for the following problem for hours now and I can't find my mistake. I want to create a responsive jumbotron background image. It works here: http://www.turfguerilla.org/index.html but not here: http://www.turfguerilla.org/thesport.html

I am using the same main.css file and the same commands in the html for both sites. So I am confused on what to do and why the outcome is different. Thank you for your help. I can also post the complete files if this is not enough.

This is the relevant part of the main.css:

```
.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 700%;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 350%;
  color: #fff;
 }

.jumbotron-homepage .jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://s16.postimg.org/ow3sxla45/jumbotron_background_4.png');
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}


.jumbotron-thesport .jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://s21.postimg.org/r6estj2lj/thesport_jumbotron_background_2.png');
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
```

This is the relevant part of index.html

```
<div class="jumbotron-homepage">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 align="center">Turf Guerilla Lacrosse</h1>
        <p align="center">Lacrosse Travelling Team</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is from thesport.html

```
<div class="jumbotron-thesport">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 align="center">The Sport</h1>
        <p align="center">of Lacrosse</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle just for the Jumbotron. Not everyone will follow unknown external links.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I didn't know about that. this is the JSFiddle for the site that works (index.html): https://jsfiddle.net/gg77ehjv/1/

And this is the one for the site that doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/9u4nc45p/

Comment: What part doesn't work? They're responding the same to me.

Comment: Yeah in JSFiddle they do. But if you open the links (if you dare to) you can see that in index.html everyhting is centered and there is no scroll bar while if you open thesport.html everything (except for the text) appers a bit to the left and there appers a scroll bar. 
Important: I am talking about smaller browser windows and mobile phones. This is when thesport.html isn't centered but index.html is.

Comment: Scroll is appearing due to iframe's fixed size. If you remove that then 1st and 2nd sites are identical.

Comment: Oh you are right. That was not too clever that I didn't see that. I added an element in css telling the iframe to be smaller with smaller display sizes and now it works. Thank you very much everyone!